# Issue of command "zypper build-install" in bash script in automating the installation

Tags: bash, shell, sh, suse

I am having a following  command which prompts the user to select one option from [1/2/c], Does anyone as idea on how to automate this process for bash script so that it doesnot prompt and get "1" as option complete the installation.

```
    $zypper source-install  R-patched
    Reading installed packages...
    Loading repository data...
    Resolving package dependencies...

    Problem: nothing provides gcc43 = 4.3.4_20091019-0.7.35 needed by gcc43-fortran-4.3.4_20091019-0.7.35.s390x
    Solution 1: do not ask to install a solvable providing gcc-fortran
    Solution 2: break gcc43-fortran-4.3.4_20091019-0.7.35.s390x by ignoring some of its dependencies

    Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): Cannot read input: bad stream or EOF.
```

Comment: What are the options? Why are you getting prompted for them? That sounds (from `above solutions`) like something is broken/wrong with the system **before** this command is being run. Is that true?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing:

```
echo "1" | zypper source-install  R-patched
```

Comment: I have also tried to give input stream like ```zypper source-install  R-patched <<< echo "1"```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.